# Pandas: Remove characters from cell in a FOR loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column labeled `Amount` which is a dollar amount. For some reason, some of the cells in this column are enclosed in quotation marks (ex: "$47.25").

I'm running this for loop and was wondering what is the best approach to remove the quotes.

```py
for f in files:
    print(f)
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header = None, nrows=1)
    print(df)
    je = df.iloc[0,1]
    df2 = pd.read_csv(f,header = 6, dtype = {'Amount':float})
    df2.to_excel(w, sheet_name = je, index = False)
```

I have attempted to strip the `"` from the value using a for loop:

```py
for cell in df2['Amount']:
    cell = cell.strip('"')
    df2['Amount']=pd.to_numeric(df2['Amount'])
```

But I am getting:

> ValueError: Unable to parse string "$-167.97" at position 0

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Given this toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Transaction": ["t1", "t2"], "Amount": ["$47.25", "'$-167.97'"]}
)
print(df)
# Outputs
  Transaction      Amount
0          t1      $47.25
1          t2  '$-167.97'
```

Instead of using a for loop, which should generally be [avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/11246056) with dataframes, you could simply remove the quotation marks from the `Amount`column like this:

```py
df["Amount"] = df["Amount"].str.replace("\'", "")

print(df)
# Outputs
  Transaction    Amount
0          t1    $47.25
1          t2  $-167.97
```